# bash separate words in string as indivduled inputs in subshell

Tags: git, bash

I have a function from a file I source that checks if files of interest have a git diff. How do I assigned a value to $patn such that  `diffs=$(git diff --name-only "$ancestor".."$source_ref" -- "$patn")` works as expected?

```
build_diff () {
  local patn
  patn=${1:-"."}

  # convert names to hash
  local this_ref
  this_ref=${2:-$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)}
  local source_ref
  source_ref=$(git show-ref -s --heads "$this_ref" || echo "$this_ref")
  local target_ref
  target_ref=$(git show-ref -s --heads "${3:-master}" || echo "$3")

  # when target and source are the same (post integration), use the branch's
  # parent as ancestor
  # When they are not the same, find the 'best' common node as ancestor
  local ancestor
  if [[ $target_ref == "$source_ref" ]]; then
    ancestor=$(git rev-parse --verify "$target_ref"^)
  else
    ancestor=$(git merge-base --all "$target_ref" "$source_ref" || git merge-base --fork-point "$target_ref" "$source_ref")
  fi

  local diffs
  diffs=$(git diff --name-only "$ancestor".."$source_ref" -- "${patn[@]}")
  echo $diffs
  if [[ -z ${diffs//[[:space:]]/} ]]; then
    echo false
  else
    echo true
  fi
}
```

-- example function call

```
FILES=".tool-versions ./other/runner/Dockerfile"
build_diff "$FILES"
```

If in the script I forget about $1 and `patn=( .tool-versions ./other/runner/Dockerfile )` then it works, but I am not able to pass in the list of files via $1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. You make `$patn` an array and then put `"${patn[@]}"` where you want to use it.

```
$patn=(foo bar baz)
 ...
echo "${patn[@]}"
```

Comment: After posting i looked at my code and realized I did not copy the right line - but you already beat me to it! How do I assign value to patn as array form the string $1?

Comment: You mean how do you expand any globs contained in `$1`? Is there a reason why you can't take `$@` instead?

Comment: if patn=$1 and I pass in  ".tool-versions ./other/runner/Dockerfile" as $1 then it does not work. (there is $2 and $3 but I can switch em around if needed)

Comment: There is a way to get it to work, but it will die on filenames with a space on it. I would recommend switching `$2` and `$3` and then slicing `$@` to get the files.

Comment: Shucks, had hopped to use defaults on the source and target refs. Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: The file that has build_diff is sourced in my ci job and has a few other functions.  How do I pass "$@" to the build_diff function?

Comment: when I remove IFS=$'\n\t' and just ref $patn - without quotes it works fine. I dont have to have an array, just need to pass to the git diff subshell